# Add config file to Quasar after build

Tags: api, vue.js, build, config, quasar

I have a UI built on Quasar, and I need to be able to have a file that our DBAs can update/replace after each deployment.The UI talks to a Laravel API, and the url is different on each environment. The environments consist of multiple dev, QA and prod sites, and all URLs can't be added on my side before build.

Is it possible to add a file that can be read from the axios.js file in the boot folder, that can be added after the build is made?